# First Load JS and Dynamic Imports in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

It was my understanding that if I was to dynamically import the only components that use a third-party library, then that library wouldn't be included in the 'First Load Bundle' shipped out to the client.

I am using Recharts in the following two components (this is the only place it's imported in the app), and I am then importing those components into the parent component like this:

```js
const UvGraphTile = dynamic(() => import("@/components/tiles/UvGraphTile"), {
  ssr: false,
});
const StravaGraphTile = dynamic(() => import("@/components/tiles/StravaGraphTile"),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

However Recharts still appears in the 'First Load Bundle', as seen in the screen shot provided. I don't know if I am making a mistake, or if my interpretation of the dynamic import for NextJS is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

[image]

Comment: When you actually run the app in the browser, do you see the dynamically imported code being loaded as a separate chunk (usually named `0.js`, `1.js`, etc.) in the Network tab?

Comment: Could you guide me where it says that Recharts appears as 'First Load Bundle'? From what I understand, bundle analyzer will generate a tree map based on the size of the modules, and not based on the order. The way you've used next/dynamic is the correct approach. May I ask if you are importing the Recharts library in someplace other than a react component, in something like a `helper.js` file?

Comment: My solution in the end was to import the the "grand" parent component of both graphs. This seemed to do the trick.

This ended up reducing my First Load Bundle size to a more acceptable 233kB.